# Raspi Pi connect to TV not HDMI-CEC ready: What can I do to make my remote control work?

Tags: hdmi, kodi, openelec

I've got a Panasonic [TX-39AW304](http://tda.panasonic-europe-service.com/docs/2z56daf0a5z3z3aa91z656ez706466z22z3d102925ea784181157fc9179a85007edc923fc7/pgrp001/pcat033/tx39aw304/921670/TX_39AW304_EN_FR_DE_IT_TK_E7GIUKLXK9CY.pdf) Television quite some time ago. The TV is  connected to the Raspberry Pi 1 Model B rev1 via a HDMI-CEC cable. On the Raspi is [Openelec](http://openelec.tv/) 6.0.3 with Kodi 15.0.2 Isengard running.

I figured out now that the Panasonic TV is not HDMI-CEC ready, as I found out [here](https://www.4clik.com/photo-video/televiseurs/id=TV2479/panasonic-tx-39aw304/) (keyword: HDMI compatible CEC). Under "System -> Settings -> System -> Input Devices -> Peripherals -> CEC adapter" I do not see any device.

Is there anything I can do to still get my remote control running with that Raspi, like adding a CEC adapter or something?

Comment: Some Panasonic devices named CEC as HDAVI Control, EZ-Sync, or VIERA Link. Try to find and enable them in the Menu.

Answer (score -2):

info from the Kodi website [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/CEC)